# python random choice against multiple lists

Tags: python

I'm having trouble explaining this so please bare with me.

I have several lists and I want to write a python script that picks an item at random from the first list, then checks that result against a "fail list," if the item isn't on the "fail list" I want to move to the next list and do the same thing until it fails.

```
#Go through these lists one by one, picking random item. 
action_heros = ['thor', 'batman', 'spiderman', 'superbart']
friends = ['joey', 'feebee', 'rachael', 'dog']
himym = ['robin', 'marshall', 'ted', 'lily', 'barney']


# fail list
simpsons = ['bart', 'homer', 'marg', 'superbart', 'dog', 'barney']


#This is how I've been trying to solve it, but I can't get the code to move to the second or third attempt 

# pick a random word from the lists
rand_action_hero = random.choice(action_heros)
rand_friend = random.choice(friends)
rand_himym = random.choice(himym)

#run the random word from each list against the checklist one by one until it fails. 
if rand_action_hero in simpsons:
    print('failed at actionheros')
#if the random word isn't in simpsons I want it to pick a new random word and try against friend, then himym
```

Thanks for any help, I'm still learning to code so it means a lot!

Comment: Do you want 1 random element from all those lists? or?

Comment: I want a random element from each list.
a random choice for each list.

Comment: What do you mean by `move it to the next list`?

Comment: And could you kindly provide the expected output from your code?

Comment: I want a random choice from the first list, check it against the fail list, if it doesn't fail, I want another random choice from the second list, and check it against the fail list until it eventually fails

Comment: I'm expecting the code to fail, I just want to know where it fails each time.  ie print('failed at friends')

Comment: Why don't you just remove the forbidden words from the lists to begin with?  Then you can choose whatever you want without checking.

Comment: I need them in because in the project I'm working with real data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know about hash sets, I would use a set for the fail list for faster lookups although it is unnecessary.

Other than that, this code should work.

```
import random

#Go through these lists one by one, picking random item. 
action_heros = ['thor', 'batman', 'spiderman', 'superbart']
friends = ['joey', 'feebee', 'rachael', 'dog']
himym = ['robin', 'marshall', 'ted', 'lily', 'barney']


# fail list
simpsons = set(['bart', 'homer', 'marg', 'superbart', 'dog', 'barney'])

# loop until it breaks
while 1:
    rand_action_hero = random.choice(action_heros)
    print(rand_action_hero)
    if rand_action_hero in simpsons:
        print("random action hero in fail list")
        break
    
    rand_friend = random.choice(friends)
    print(rand_friend)
    if rand_friend in simpsons:
        print("random friend in fail list")
        break

    rand_himym = random.choice(himym)
    print(rand_himym)
    if rand_himym in simpsons:
        print("random himym in fail list")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all your choices into a list, then loop through them testing if it's in the fail list.

```
for listname, choice in [('action_heros', rand_action_hero), ('friends', rand_friend), ('himym', rand_himym)]: 
    if choice in simpsons:
        print(f'failed at {listname}')
        break
else:
    print('All tests succeeded')
```

You could avoid hard-coding all the list names and variables by turning the separate lists into a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of repeatedly picking a new choice, I'd suggest removing all items in the fail-list from your input.

For example:

```
action_heros = [item for item in ['thor', 'batman', 'spiderman', 'superbart'] if item not in simpsons]

['thor', 'batman', 'spiderman']
```

This makes sure you always get a valid choice.

```
simpsons = ['bart', 'homer', 'marg', 'superbart', 'dog', 'barney']
action_heros = ['thor', 'batman', 'spiderman', 'superbart']
random.choice([item for item in action_heros if item not in simpsons])
```

You can do the same by converting your input to sets and use the setdifference:

```
random.choice(tuple(set(action_heros) - set(simpsons)))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

We first create a dictionary with all the lists combined with their respectful title, and we loop over each element in that dictionary and compare a `random.choice()` from that element with the `fail_list`. and if it exists in the fail list we continue the loop, now if it doesn't exist in the loop we break/stop that loop.

### My code:

```
import random

lists = {"action heros":['thor', 'batman', 'spiderman', 'superbart'],
         "friends":['joey', 'feebee', 'rachael', 'dog'],
         "himym":['robin', 'marshall', 'ted', 'lily', 'barney']}

fail_list = ['bart', 'homer', 'marg', 'superbart', 'dog', 'barney']


for elements in lists:
  if random.choice(lists[elements]) in fail_list:
    continue
  else:
    print("failed at {0}".format(elements))
    break
```

### Output

- code won't have any fixed output since it runs with a `random.choice()` but...

```
>>> failed at himym
```

## Diagram

[image]